# Importing data from a csv file to mysql db

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load data from a csv file that is still in excel. So far this is the statement that I have as my sql query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\J03299\\Desktop\\TMETER.csv'
INTO TABLE edata
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY "" LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(Year,Month,Day,MJD,xpiles,xstacks,Utilites);
```

The file is called TMETER and it has 7 columns. It has 366 rows. I am able to only read the first row and only the first four columns(till MJD) but everything else is null after that. Secondly in the second row it puts all the columns from my file (TMETER.csv) in row 124 into the first column of the second row in my edata table. I am confused as to

1. Why doesn't it read the data from column piles,stacks ,utilites? (mind you the column names in the csv file are weird and not the same as my edata table e.g in database table it is piles while in actual csv file it is x(piles), stacks in table but y(stacks) in csv file. Mysql doesn't not allow me to create etable names with this format so I had to improvise. Could this be why it is not reading and mapping from the csv file to the table in mysql?
2. Why is my statement putting the first row in my csv file in the first row in mysql table but then skipping all the down to row 124 and then inserting all columns from csv file into first column of mysql database table?

Sorry my English is not good.
Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the command, it should give a message like `Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0`. If there are any warnings, type `SHOW WARNINGS` to see what they were.

This sounds like behavior I sometimes get when the line ending is wrong. Try opening your document in a code editor and checking to make sure your lines actually end with \n. If that's inconvenient, you could also just try dropping the table and reimporting with `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'` or `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` and see if that fixes it.

Regarding field names: This command ignores field names in your text file. All it does is match the first column to the first field indicated in parentheses (in your case, Year) the second column to the second field in parentheses (Month), and so on. If you have field names at the top of your file, you should skip over them by adding IGNORE 1 LINES just before the parentheses with the list of fields.

Comment: Im not sure if you understand the problem and thank you for replying. I do not get any warning when i execute this statement. In my csv file i have 7 columns. My statement reads every value upto the MJD column. After that it doesn't not read anything. If incluyde the actual name of the column in my sql staement-x(piles) -which if the column namethat is when it throws an error stating  Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(piles),y(stacks))'

Comment: i do not know how to read data into my table with this column name and i think this is why it is skipping all the way to row 124

Comment: i opened the document with a code editor and the each line was being terminated by ,

Comment: OK YOUR SOLUTION WORKED PARTIALLY...I USED IGNORE 1 LINE AND IT is reading all columns from csv file into database. Problem is it is still skipping rows...it now goes all the way to row 156

Comment: Try looking at row 156 (which may actually be row 157) and see whether there are any unusual characters there. Maybe a text field with a line break inside it?

Comment: it doesnt make sense. Why would it start with the first row and skip all the way to row 124? doesn't make sense man. I t doesnt even get to row 2..it ignores the first line because i put ignore 1 lines to ignore the row headers. I know it is something to do with my end of line. When i open the csv file in a code editor my lines end with a , so is that the problem perhaps

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant that it got to line 156 correctly and then started acting up. In that case, whatever you find on line 156 may actually be the _correct_ line delimiter, which was previously not appearing in your file. It's difficult to troubleshoot this kind of thing without being able to get my hands on it...

Comment: hey buddy i solved the problem. Apparently i was using year as the primary key(and it was NOT unique) so it was only reading the first row with 2012 and not any other subsequent row because they were the same